# Call to a member function notify() on null

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, notifications

im having problem to send notification to admin when the user report a post.
once the user report a post it should send notification about the report to admin . but now its sending notification to user of the post. how to solve it.

Store controller

```
 public function store(Request $request,Postqs $postqs,$id,Report $report)
  {


    $add_item = new Report;
    $add_item->item= $request->input("item");
    $add_item->repo= $request->input("repo");
    $add_item->user_id= Auth::user()->id;
    $add_item->postqs_id=$id;
    $add_item->save();

  $report = Report::find($id);
  $postqs = Postqs::find($id);
  $report->admin->notify(new ReportPost($report));
   return back();

    }
```

notification.Report_post

```
  public function toDatabase($notifiable)
 {

     return [

       'postqs'=>$this->postqs,

       'admin'=>Auth::guard('admin')->guest()

     ];
 }
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($report)` and check what you're getting. Check what the property `admin` actually contains. We have no idea.

Comment: its showing null

Comment: Then you need to figure out if the `$id` is wrong or if it is your model that's wrong and doesn't return what it should.

Comment: var_dump($report->admin) showing null

Comment: var_dump($report) showing object(App\Report)#336 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(6) "report" ["casts":protected]=> array(1) { ["item"]=> string(5) "array" } ..................................................